# modify docker run command in pipeline.yml

Tags: java, docker, azure-cli

I'm running blankdots/jena-fuseki:fuseki3.17.0 in azure cloud and now JVM seems to take all memory from my container (I https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/). To decrease the amount of memory used by JVM I should just add -e JVM_ARGS=-Xmx2g  into the docker run command

But I don't know how to change my yml below

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Create Fuseki Web App 
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}
      scriptType: pscore
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: >
        $(scriptFilesPath)/Create-FusekiWebApp.ps1
        -AppServicePlanName $(appServicePlanName)
        -ContainerImageName $(fusekiContainerImageName)
        -ContainerMountNameIdentifier $(fusekiContainerMountNameIdentifier)
        -ContainerMountPath $(fusekiContainerMountPath)
        -Location $(location)
        -ResourceGroupName $(resourceGroupName)
        -StorageAccountFileShareName $(fusekiStorageAccountFileShareName)
        -StorageAccountName $(fusekiStorageAccountName)
        -WebAppName $(fusekiWebAppName)
      failOnStandardError: false
      powerShellIgnoreLASTEXITCODE: true


  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Restart Web App
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}
      scriptType: pscore
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: >
        az webapp config appsettings set 
        --name $(fusekiWebAppName) 
        --resource-group $(resourceGroupName)
        --settings JVM_ARGS='-Xmx2g'
        az webapp restart 
        --resource-group $(resourceGroupName) 
        --name $(fusekiWebAppName) 
      failOnStandardError: true
```

Answer (score 0):

So, running `-e JVM_ARGS=-Xmx2g` will add an environment variable within the docker container.

In your case, since you're running an app service, you can accomplish the same thing by updating your `Create-FusekiWebApp.ps1` script to include a line that sets the environment variable in the Azure Web App itself.

It would look something like this:

```
az webapp config appsettings set -g Your_AzureAppServiceResourceGroup -n Your_AzureAppServiceName --settings JVM_ARGS=-Xmx2g
```

Here's Microsoft's documentation on setting app service environment variables using the CLI:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_appsettings_set